# hook_node_view OR template_preprocess_page

Tags: nodes

I have some data to be extracted from external sources. I want to display those data in a custom template tpl page ( **page--zzz.tpl.php** ) . I had implemented **hook_node_view** in my module, and with the **node->nid**, output the data to be displayed on a **node.tpl.php** page.

However, the designer wanted to use the full width of the page, so I had to display the collected data in the **page-zzz.tpl** page, instead of just in the **node.tpl.php**, so I have moved my function for collecting the data from my module to the **template.tpl.php**, and inside the function **template_preprocess_page**, with the node->nid, I collect the same data.

Is that correct? Everything would have been much easier if I had been able to access to the **$page** variable inside of the *hook_node_view* function. I tried but I did not succeed!!!

Please advice me. Now it is working but I am hesitating whether there was need to move the collecting data function from my module to the template tpl page.

Answer (score 1):

`hook_node_view()` is *not* really suitable for loading anymore data. There is a `hook_node_load()` hook, which you'll receive an array of all nodes that site is about to load. 
Note that this is only for loading, and that doesn't mean the user is on a `node/XYZ` page. You will probably need to add a URL argument match to make sure you load only the data related to the given node. Otherwise, pull all the information at once, and store them in each `$node` variable, which is passed by reference (all PHP 5 objects are).

The reason to use `node_load` hook over `node_view` hooks is that all modules implementing preprocess and view hooks now have access to this new piece of node. Otherwise, a hook_node_view is OK.

Secondly, you do not need to load them again in `hook_preprocess_page` at all. For Drupal 7 and later, `hook_page_alter()` is recommended. Since you store the data in `hook_node_view/load` hook, simply place the content in the regions you need. If this is theme specific, `hook_preprocess_page()` is better, but most of the contribs that take over entire page contents tend to use `hook_preprocess_page()`. Besides, you will have access to the renderable array because other preprocess functions are not executed at that moment.

You can get the current node like below (make sure you add `arg()` conditions to check the page router is `node/%node`)

```
$node = menu_get_object();
```

This `$node` object will contain the data you stored in the load/view hook. Make sure you pass the first argument to `hook_page_alter(&$build)` by reference, and place the content anywhere you want like god.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply, that I will study carefully. However, I thought that the region was exclusive of $page, i. e., print render ( $page[name_of_region] ) would print the region, I didn't know that it was accessible through $node.

Comment: Store raw data in the `node_load` hook. Process them in the `page_alter` hook.